# Qt: Style the >> arrow when a QToolBar is too small

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I have a QToolBar with **QToolButtons**. When the main window is too small, it will show a ">>" button , to extend the view into multiple lines and show all QToolButtons.

**How can I style this ">>" button?** I'd like to change the icon and the background color.

I already tried with these selectors: QToolButton::menu-indicator, QToolButton::menu-button, QToolButton::down-arrow. Doesn't work.

How can I change the color and the width of the ">>" button?

```
QToolButton {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #3A3939;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

QToolButton:hover, QToolButton::menu-button:hover {
    background: #787876;
}

QToolButton::checked{
    background: #484846;
    border: 1px solid #787876;
}

QToolButton:pressed, QToolButton::menu-button:pressed {
    background: #787876;
}

QToolButton[popupMode="1"]{
/* only for MenuButtonPopup */
    padding-right: 30px;
    background: red;
}
QToolButton[popupMode="2"]{
/* only for OSC Server Status */
    padding-right: 30px;
    background: #484846;
}
QToolButton[popupMode="2"]:hover{
    background: #787876;
}
QToolButton::down-arrow{
} 
/* the subcontrols below are used only in the MenuButtonPopup mode */
QToolButton::menu-button{
}

QToolButton::menu-button:hover{
    background: #787876;
}
QToolButton::menu-button:pressed{
}
QToolButton::menu-indicator{
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: You have any code or JSFiddle for us to work off of, so that others down the road can find this useful. Thanks!

Comment: I edited the post with the CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it via `CSS`, however it can be done using a custom styling:

- Inherit a new class from `QStyle` / `QCommonStyle`.
- Reimplement `pixelMetric` to change a size of the button.
- `Qt4`: Create a slot `standardIconImplementation` to change an icon of the button.
- `Qt5`: Reimplement `standardIcon` to change an icon of the button.
- create this style and use `setStyle` to apply it to the toolbar (or to the application).

Reimplemented methods:

```
virtual int MyStyle::pixelMetric(PixelMetric pm, const QStyleOption* option, const QWidget* widget) const override
{
  if (pm == QStyle::PM_ToolBarExtensionExtent) 
    return mySize; // width of a toolbar extension button in a horizontal toolbar and the height of the button in a vertical toolbar
  return QStyle::pixelMetric(pm, option, widget);
}

Q_SLOT QIcon MyStyle::standardIconImplementation(StandardPixmap standardIcon, const QStyleOption * option = 0, const QWidget * widget = 0) const
{
    switch (standardIcon)
    {
    case QStyle::SP_ToolBarHorizontalExtensionButton :
        return m_toolBarHExtendButtonIcon;

    case QStyle::SP_ToolBarVerticalExtensionButton :
        return m_toolBarVExtendButtonIcon;
    }

    return QStyle::standardIconImplementation(standardIcon, option, widget);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot!

However, inheriting from QStyle implies to reimplement a lot of functions. I chose to inherit from QCleanLookStyle (but there are many other nice styles) to reimplement only pixelMetric and standardIconImplementation.

For those who chose to use QCleanLookStyle as i did, don't forget to call correct parent function in pixelMetric, otherwise you will get link errors.

```
virtual int pixelMetric(PixelMetric pm, const QStyleOption* option, const QWidget* widget) const override 
{
if (pm == QStyle::PM_ToolBarExtensionExtent)
return 1234; 
return QCleanlooksStyle::pixelMetric(pm, option, widget);
}
```

Thanks for the answer, it works.

> You cannot do it via `CSS`, however it can be done using a custom
>   styling:
>
> - Inherit a new class from `QStyle` / `QCommonStyle`.
> - Reimplement `pixelMetric` to change a size of the button.
> - `Qt4`: Create a slot `standardIconImplementation` to change an icon of the button.
> - `Qt5`: Reimplement `standardIcon` to change an icon of the button.
> - create this style and use `setStyle` to apply it to the toolbar (or to the application).
>
> Reimplemented methods:
>
> ```
> virtual int MyStyle::pixelMetric(PixelMetric pm, const QStyleOption* option, const QWidget* widget) const override
> {
>   if (pm == QStyle::PM_ToolBarExtensionExtent) 
>     return mySize; // width of a toolbar extension button in a horizontal toolbar and the height of the button in a vertical toolbar
>   return QStyle::pixelMetric(pm, option, widget);
> }
>
> Q_SLOT QIcon MyStyle::standardIconImplementation(StandardPixmap standardIcon, const QStyleOption * option = 0, const QWidget * widget
> ```
>
> = 0) const
>       {
>           switch (standardIcon)
>         {
>         case QStyle::SP_ToolBarHorizontalExtensionButton :
>             return m_toolBarHExtendButtonIcon;
>
> ```
>   case QStyle::SP_ToolBarVerticalExtensionButton :
>       return m_toolBarVExtendButtonIcon;
>   }
>
>     return QStyle::standardIconImplementation(standardIcon, option, widget);
> }
> ```

Comment: It's better to add your info as a comment because I bet this comment-like answer will be removed soon.